# MySQL only starts in safe-mode

Tags: mysql

It appears that MySQL instance only starts when I issue the skip-grant-tables and when I go to start it the normal way, service mysql start I am getting the cannot connect to socket.

I have seen plenty of solutions but nothing has worked.

```
[client] 
port = 3306 
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 

[mysqld_safe] 
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock nice = 0

[mysqld] 
user = mysql 
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid 
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
port = 3306 
basedir = /usr 
datadir = /var/lib/mysql 
tmpdir = /tmp 
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql 
skip-external-locking 
bind-address = 127.0.0.1 
key_buffer = 16M 
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

---

```
/var/run/mysqld# ls -atlr 
total 0 
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 720 Oct 14 01:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 40 Oct 14 02:33 .
```

Comment: Please post the errors printed in the logs. Please post the location and permission of the socket if it's a unix domain socket. Please post the content of my.cnf.

Comment: [client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

Comment: /var/run/mysqld# ls -atlr
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 22 root  root  720 Oct 14 01:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql  40 Oct 14 02:33 .

Comment: You have several problems there. The directory `/var/run/mysqld` is owned by `root:root` when it should be `mysql:mysql`. The server `[mysqld]` binds to `127.0.0.1:3306` for tcp connections but the client will connect to `*:3306`. You didn't post the error.

Comment: Some people posts comments as answers. But you managed to post in comments.

Comment: I have put the additional information from your comments in the actual post. You should use edit for adding additional information to your question rather than adding comments, one reason being that comments are hard to format. 

Also look at the edit I have made and make sure the file contents are correctly formatted with its line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to overcome

1. Go to **Edit->Preferences** menu under MySQL Workbench.
2. uncheck "**Safe Update**".
3. Restart WorkBench.

attached is the screenshot [Screenshot from MySQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCx38.png).

Comment: Hi Avits, it is drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql      mysql        40 Oct 14 02:33 mysqld

Comment: root@ip-10-1-0-83:/var/run# mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: Here is something else.

Comment: root@ip-10-1-0-83:/# /etc/init.d/mysql start
start: Job is already running: mysql
root@ip-10-1-0-83:/# ps -ef | grep mysql
mysql    10862     1 14 13:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root     10908 31430  0 13:35 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
root@ip-10-1-0-83:/# mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
root@ip-10-1-0-83:/# cd /var/run/mysqld/
root@ip-10-1-0-83:/var/run/mysqld# ls
root@ip-10-1-0-83:/var/run/mysqld#
When I cd /tmp I see a mysql.sock but its red and doesn't go away after stop

Comment: 63985.611061] init: mysql main process (14267) terminated with status 1
[63985.611071] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[63986.284531] init: mysql post-start process (14268) terminated with status 1
[63986.289613] type=1400 audit(1476452350.138:345): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=14309 comm="apparmor_parser"
[63986.637328] init: mysql main process (14320) terminated with status 1
[63986.637338] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped

Comment: @MichaelW. - I wish I can decipher your comment. Logs are line oriented. Without carriage returns, it's just hard, if not impossible, to read them.